# Linux script How to open new terminal and run commands in it

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am writing a script which will take users input and then run following command in **new** terminal.

I am working on bigger "script", but for testing I created this little version of my problem.

newtermtest.sh

```
okegreen='\033[92m'

while true
read -p "Input Selection: " mainmenuinput
do
  #find the name of instaled terminal then run new window of it and run bash in it !
  #on my computer I have instaled x-terminal-emulator: so testing on it   ---- NOT WORKING YET
  case $mainmenuinput in
    "0")
    x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c 'nmap -sV -sC 189.55.23.174 -vvv'"
    ;;
    "1")
    path=$(pwd)
    x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c 'cd $path;touch silk.txt'"
    ;;
    *)
    break;
  esac
done

echo -e "${okegreen}leaving programe..."
```

I have found that something like `x-terminal-emulator -e {command}` should work, but when I run it I have the following error and the screen just flashes.

returned message:
`QDir::exists: Empty or null file name`

Then I would need something to keep the terminal up, I found `--noclose or -hold` tags, but I can't test it util I find the working command.

Do you have some experiences with opening new terminal from bash script ?
Iam opened for any hints.

**Some temporary solution which works now:**

```
x-terminal-emulator -e 'nmap -sV -sC 189.55.23.174 -vvv'
```

I used just `-e` to execute command and with nmap it is working now.
I will figure out other commands and I will try to put it in complex script with more types of terminals.

Thanks All for suggestions.

Comment: Where does your `x-terminal-emulator` point to? it is supposed to be a symlink to something. Why not invoking the terminal directly via its executable?

Comment: `QDir::exists` _implies_ that you're using a KDE/Qt terminal emulator, but that's just a guess. This isn't a generic problem; it's one specific to the individual terminal you're using.

Comment: Note that over in the GNOME world, `-e` is no longer recommended, and one uses `gnome-terminal -- bash -c '...'` instead of `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '...'`. But again, this question can't be answered without specifying a specific individual terminal to test against.

Comment: Also, are you sure the "screen just flashes" isn't your terminal showing a copy of bash doing exactly what it's supposed to, finishing, then exiting? Because if that's it, what you have is code working exactly the way it's designed to. (There's no reason that `cd $path; touch silk.txt` would take longer than a flash).

Comment: Also, note that the code you have now has serious security bugs. The _safe_ way to write `cd $path` has `$path` treated as data by the shell executing it; here, though, the _outer_ shell is doing the expansion, so the _inner_ shell only sees the result as a literal embedded in the code. Literals in the code can do things that data can't -- code can contain something like `$(rm -rf ~)`, for example, and it'll be treated as a command to run instead of as a perfectly harmless part of your directory name.

Comment: Also, for terminals that _do_ support `terminal -e '...command...'`, that `...command...` is _already_ run in a shell (albeit often `sh` rather than something more capable) -- so putting `bash -c` inside it means you're having the terminal spawn a shell that spawns a _second_ shell. Whereas with terminals that support `-- commandname arg1 arg2 ...` there's no implicit shell at all; less to go wrong, less happening behind your back, etc.